# Having trouble giving my JPanel functionality

Tags: java, user-interface

*This is my first time using GUI, I seem to miss something my eye can't catch. The code looks fine to me however when i submit it to autoLab I get this error, which I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

```
{"correct":false,"feedback":"(class java.lang.NumberFormatException) 
 Error while attempting to call static method q2() on input [1]}
```

**The problem question is q5:**

Write a public static method named q5 that takes no parameters and returns a JPanel. 
      The panel will contain 1 JTextField with any number of columns, 1 JButton with any label, 
     and 1 JLabel. The panel will have functionality such that when a user enters a number into 
     the text field (we'll call this value x) and presses the button the label will display the 
      y-value of a parabola in standard form (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zukjgk9iry) 
     where a=5.37, b=-6.07, and c=2.0 at the x-value from the text field

**Hint:** If you store y in the wrapper class Double instead of the primitive double you can 
     call toString on it to convert it to a string that can be used as the text for the label
      Tip: After clicking the button you may have to resize your window to see the result since 
      the frame will not automatically resize to fit the new text

Do not create any JFrames in your problem set questions. Doing so will crash the 
      auto-grader since the grading server does not have a screen to display the JFrame. 
      Instead, only return the required JPanel in the problem set methods and test with a JFrame 
      in your main method, or other helper methods that are not graded

This is the code I wrote

```
public static JPanel q5() {


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
    panel.add(textField);               
    JLabel label = new JLabel("hello!");
    panel.add(label);
    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            double a=5.37*Math.pow(x, 2);
            double b=-6.07*x;
            double c=2.0; 

            String answer= ("y = " + a+ b +c);
            label.setText(answer);

        }
    });



    return panel;

}
```

can you explain where I went wrong , thank you.

Comment: What is method q2()? What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

So, a NumberFormatException can occur when trying to parse a String, when the String does not contain a number. You did not give enough information to be sure, but I am going to presume that it is this line that causes the problem:

```
        int x = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

One thing that strikes me as odd, is that you initialize the JTextField with 5 columns:

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
```

Is that what you want? If you wanted to pre-initialize the text field with a value of 5, you would have to do it like this:

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("5");
```

Comment: oh ok, is this something I should be adding? 
     catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
           
           
        }

Comment: Well, that certainly would prevent the crash, but I think a more clean solution would be to use a JFormattedTextField that rejects any input that is not a number and to use an if statement that checks for an empty input String.